# Dying Hydrangea

Tags: flowers, hydrangea

I have had this hydrangea for a couple of weeks. When I first got it, it had beautiful, big blue blooms. But, now it seems to be dying.
I'm keeping it in a place where it is shaded for most of the day, except the morning. 
What should I do?
Thank you in advance![image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you give us some more details. How much water did you put, what type of soil is in the pot, where are you keeping it (inside the house, outside). Have you applied any pesticide, any chemicals in contact. More information, the better.

Comment: I have watered it every day. The soil in the pot is just the normal soil I got in my backyard, I think the pH is between 6.8-7. I am keeping it outdoors. And I havent used any pesticide or chemicals in it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a 'floral hydrangea'...one that was purchased in a floral shop?  If that is true then what is happening makes sense.  You transplanted into a larger pot (good size, what soil did you use).  Did you purchase this plant already planted in this pot?  If so then the florist transplanted it to be able to charge more, which is fine.

What they should have explained was this hydrangea is not used to being out of doors.  How to acclimate the plant to the out of doors.  These plants are usually only made to be pretty for awhile, short term perishable.

You most certainly can transplant them into larger pots or even out of doors in the garden IF they are acclimated correctly.  If planted in a  pot, use only potting soil.

This plant is not dead at all.  The blooms are dying as they should.  Cut them off without leaving a stump.  If they are completely dry then they can be used for a dried flower arrangement.  If not, put the stem of that flower in a tiny bit of water; 1/2 inch.  As the water dries the flower dries.

I am seeing the results of a lot of salt and/or full sun reaching the leaves beneath those flowers.  Those dried and curling leaf margins are showing this plant has been over fertilized or you are using tap water to water your plant or it has had some bright direct sun that 'burnt' the leaves because the leaves weren't hardened off to full sun first.

Keep this plant in FULL shade.  No direct sun.  I think your plant should be hardened off a bit more to adjust to direct sun then planted in your garden in partial shade.

Do you have other acid loving plants that are doing well such as Rhododendrons, Azaleas, Camellias?  If those plants are healthy that means the pH should be correct for your Hydrangea.

Let us know what you want to do with this plant.  He is a very good looking specimen, honest.  Out of doors is where he belongs and we can help.

Comment: Thank you!
I got this as a gift, but I think that it was purchased in a floral shop. It came in a smaller pot, but I changed it into this. 
I am using tap water. Should I be using water bought in a store?
I do not have the other plants that you mentioned, but I have another hydrangea (looks the same, but has flowers that change from green to pink). That one seems to be doing fine, but it already had stronger stems when I got it.
Should I cut the flowers now or is there any chance they can regain their color?
Ultimately, I would like to remove it from the pot and plant it in my garden.

Comment: Interesting, you are noticing the correct stuff to notice.  Pink hydrangea means alkaline soil.  Acid soils make blue hydrangea out of the very same plants.  Yours is used to acidic pH.  Those flowers are DONE.  They are only meant to produce seed, babies.  I collected blue and purple hydrangea flowers from my client's shrubs then used them and baby's breath to decorate my Xmas tree, stunning.  Is your pinkish hydrangea a 'mop head' too?  Like the flowers on this hydrangea?  A big round collection of flowers?  Then that means your soil is a bit alkaline...and you might end up having pink flwrs

Comment: Purchase distilled water, if you are able, to water plants in pots.  Our tap waters are so suspect for lots of awful chemistry. Fluoride is industrial waste...seriously, everyone needs to know about this really weird thing our country and others got hoodwinked into doing, into believing so much they give BABIES fluoride tablets.  Not one shred of evidence or tests that show any 'benefit' to humans and animals and plants.  Amazing thing to learn more about.  Causes white spots and brown pits on teeth.  Plus an awful lot more damage to bones and brains.

Comment: Do you have any relatives or friends that live close but have a well for water?  I would get a big water bottle and fill it up with the well water.  Or use distilled, I just hope it is truly distilled.  The only way to get fluoride out of water.  Of course it is in all canned goods, preserved foods, all sodas, all fruity drinks, all bottled water, Cheerios and Fruit Loop cereals.  Our body puts it in our bones and there is accumulates.  Just fyi...great documentaries on this subject...